# org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet Not Found

Tags: java, spring, servlets

Okay this has been bugging the hell out of me and I've looked around, and every other thread says go to deployment assembly. Problem is when I go there, theres no 'maven depencies' to click on.

Like in this thread:
     [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet not found with VMWare vFabric tc Server and maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362118/org-springframework-web-servlet-)     dispatcherservlet-not-found-with-vmware-vfabric

I get to that screen and theres no maven depencies to click.

My web.xml is:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and the -servlet.xml

```
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorialspoint" />

<bean     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm using STS tools/Eclipse.

heres the pom. all the jars are in the folder java resources/libraries/maven dependecies

```
     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SpringMVC</groupId>
 <artifactId>SpringMVC</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>SpringMVC</name>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.json</groupId>
  <artifactId>json</artifactId>
  <version>20090211</version>
   </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

 <build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src</directory>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </resource>
</resources>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    </plugin>
   </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Exception is:

```
ava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:486)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:113)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1133)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1072)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5368)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5660)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

EDIT: I got it to compile but now get

WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HelloWeb/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb

Comment: Add your entire exception stack in query.

Comment: @RohitGaikwad okay I added it

Comment: show your controller and add this javax.servlet dependency to your pom.xml :

Answer (score 0):

Try with this;
Use **Servlet API 2.5** and change your `web.xml` file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and `spring-servlet.xml` file to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd ">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorialspoint"></context:component-scan>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"><!-- Here, the InternalResourceViewResolver class is used for the ViewResolver. -->
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property><!-- prefix can be any thing -->
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
```

**EDIT:**
You have to include maven dependency for spring 3.x as below

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
 <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

As per your query in comments; Here in this case Spring is not creating default constructor so better move on to setter injection or create a default constructor.

Comment: Nope still getting the same error. All I'm trying to do is make a spring MVC application. On the tutorial it says to convert it to war but I'm just using STS and converting to maven for the pom.xml

Comment: There is an X on the project indicating an error but I have no idea where

Comment: adding your edit gives me org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer

Comment: make use of setter injection instead of constructor for this issue, reference  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490022/error-creating-bean-with-name-org-springframework-web-servlet-mvc-annotation-de

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add these dependencies in your pom.xml file，Which dependency on what I hava forgotten.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I added <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
But now I'm just getting a 404 and No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HelloWeb/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'

Comment: I think what if you abandon <plugin> also "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HelloWeb/] "

Answer (score 0):

Hope fully this will the best Answer:

i was facing problem i download the eclipse Noen.3 and Dirctly Creating the Maven project. Same Problem was occur that Server not start: DispatcherServlet class not Found Error:

1. i created the simple Dynamic Web Project and convert the project into Maven project

Steps: Right Click on the project configure->Convert to maven project

For Further Details i followed below the link 
http://javawebtutor.com/articles/spring/spring-mvc-hibernate-crud-example.php